# typo3 custom widget viewhelper

Tags: typo3, viewhelper

I created a custom widget `viewhelper` for an extension which works fine in an empty typo3 8.7 installation. But when I use it on needed project with same code it causes an error:

```
#1289422564: initiateSubRequest() can not be called if there is no valid controller extending TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\Core\Widget\AbstractWidgetController Got "NULL" in class ...
```

Did somebody have an error like this before or does someone know what causes this type of error?

```
<!-- This is the View List.html-->


{namespace Exhibitors = MyVendorName\MyExhibitors\ViewHelpers}

<ul class="second_lvl">
    <Exhibitors:widget.AtoZNav objects="{feUserData}" as="filteredExhibitors" property="company">
        <Exhibitors:widget.sort objects="{filteredExhibitors}" as="sortedExhibitors" property="company">
            <f:for each="{filteredExhibitors}" as="feUser">
                <li class="navLink">
                    {feUser.company}<br />
                    {feUser.company}
                    {feUser.www}<br />
                </li>
            </f:for>
        </Exhibitors:widget.sort>
    </Exhibitors:widget.AtoZNav>
</ul>
<f:link.action action="show">show detail page</f:link.action>
```

---

```
<?php
/**
 * This is the SortViewHelper
 */

namespace MyVendorName\MyExhibitors\ViewHelpers\Widget;


class SortViewHelper extends \TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\Core\Widget\AbstractWidgetViewHelper
{
    /**
     * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryResultInterface $objects
     * @param string $as
     * @param string $property
     * @return string
     */
    public function render(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryResultInterface $objects, $as, $property)
    {
       return $this->initiateSubRequest();
    }
}
```

---

```
<?php
/**
 * This is the Sort Controller
 */

namespace MyVendorName\MyExhibitors\ViewHelpers\Widget\Controller;


class SortController extends \TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\Core\Widget\AbstractWidgetController
{
    /**
     * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryResultInterface
     */
    protected $objects;

    public function initializeAction()
    {
        $this->objects = $this->widgetConfiguration['objects'];
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed string $order
     */
    public function indexAction($order = \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryInterface::ORDER_DESCENDING)
    {
        $order = ($order == \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryInterface::ORDER_ASCENDING) ? \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryInterface::ORDER_DESCENDING : \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryInterface::ORDER_ASCENDING;
        $query = $this->objects->getQuery();
        $query->setOrderings(array($this->widgetConfiguration['property'] => $order));
        $modifiedObjects = $query->execute();
        $this->view->assign('contentArguments', array($this->widgetConfiguration['as'] => $modifiedObjects));
        $this->view->assign('order', $order);
    }
}
```

---

```
<?php
/**
 * This is AtoZNav ViewHelper
 */

namespace MyVendorName\MyExhibitors\ViewHelpers\Widget;

class AtoZNavViewHelper extends \TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\Core\Widget\AbstractWidgetViewHelper
{
    /**
     * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryResultInterface $objects
     * @param string $as
     * @param string $property
     * @return string
     */
    public function render(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryResultInterface $objects, $as, $property)
    {
       return $this->initiateSubRequest();
    }
}
```

---

```
<?php
/**
 * This is the Controller
 */

namespace MyVendorName\MyExhibitors\ViewHelpers\Widget\Controller;


class AtoZNavController extends \TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\Core\Widget\AbstractWidgetController
{
    /**
     * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryResultInterface
     */
    protected $objects;

    public function initializeAction()
    {
        $this->objects = $this->widgetConfiguration['objects'];
    }

    /**
     * @param string $char
     * @throws \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Exception\InvalidQueryException
     */
    public function indexAction($char = '%')
    {
        $query = $this->objects->getQuery();
        $query->matching($query->like($this->widgetConfiguration['property'], $char . '%'));
        $modifiedObjects = $query->execute();
        $this->view->assign('contentArguments', array($this->widgetConfiguration['as'] => $modifiedObjects));
        $this->view->assign('letters', range('A', 'Z'));
        $this->view->assign('char', $char);
    }
}
```

Comment: Same TYPO3 version?
Cleared cache in install tool?
Cleared autoload directory in typo3temp?

Comment: Yes it is the same version 8.7.x, all caches cleared

Comment: Please share code of your ViewHelper

Comment: @HeinzSchilling i added the code above

Comment: I had similar errors when extension is not installed correct. Try to deinstall extension and install again.

Comment: did something helped have the same issue that my widget crashes the site without 
500 error logs are directing me somewhere else :( and reinstall the extension didn´t helped also deleted caches

Comment: Try it by using the viewhelper in this style <Exhibitors:widget.AtoZNav... without using namespace 
{namespace Exhibitors = MyVendorName\MyExhibitors\ViewHelpers}
on top of the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same error. You need to inject your controller, like it is done in the fluid pagination widget. This part is missing in the book.

```
<?php
/**
 * This is the SortViewHelper
 */

namespace MyVendorName\MyExhibitors\ViewHelpers\Widget;


class SortViewHelper extends \TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\Core\Widget\AbstractWidgetViewHelper
{

    protected $controller;

    /**
     * @param Controller/SortController $controller
     */
    public function injectSortController(Controller\SortController $controller)
    {
        $this->controller = $controller;
    }

    /**
     * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryResultInterface $objects
     * @param string $as
     * @param string $property
     * @return string
     */
    public function render(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryResultInterface $objects, $as, $property)
    {
       return $this->initiateSubRequest();
    }
}
```